# Bake sound to F Curve giving square curves?

Tags: animation, import, audio, graph-editor

Just working my way through [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OAes-ITNaGA#t=306) . . . Got to about 5.55 in the video and hit a snag.

My [soundfile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5yr6eyp3699gln2/fireTheLazerCannon01001Rev.wav) loads into the graph editor, but instead of appearing as a series of curves, it shows up as collection of squared-off straight lines.

[image]

Here are the import settings:

[image]

. . . and [.blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/prkebt7bhyetyjr/mrGoogleyEyes01002Rev.blend) file.

Anybody know what gives?

Comment: It depends on your audio file. spikes are made when the pitch is different.
Try to use another sound file to get spikey curves.

Comment: This question (and its answer) are valuable. Closing it for reasons of being "off-topic" is just wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was that in setting up the custom property 'Sound'. In the video, the tutor enters '0.0' into the Property Value. I didn't notice the decimal and entered '0', thus switching the property to 'integer' instead of the desired 'float'.

I removed the keyframes from the Sound property, edited the Property Value to '0.0', added a keyframe and reimported the sound (bake sound to fcurve).

Comment: For some reason, your solution didn't work for me initially. However after restarting Blender, I could reproduce the error and your solution worked.

Answer (score -2):

You should use first a AudioEditor like Audacity to see if your sound's wave is squared, or maybe it coul be that you are using "Constant" intropolation mode.

Comment: You can't change the interpolation after baking from audio.